# Reverting temporary assignment in C++

Tags: c++, variable-assignment

In a visitor context, I need to temporarily set a variable before visiting children, and revert that variable afterward.  I'm using the following code, but I'm sure there's a more elegant and proper way to do this:

```
template <typename TYPE> class TemporaryAssignment {
protected:
    TYPE& mVariable;
    TYPE mOriginalValue;
public:
    TemporaryAssignment(TYPE& inVariable, TYPE inValue) 
        : mVariable(inVariable), mOriginalValue(inVariable) {
        mVariable = inValue;
    }
    ~TemporaryAssignment(void) {
        mVariable = mOriginalValue;
    }
};
```

This allows me to write something like the following:

```
{
    ...
    TemporaryAssignment<string> t(myVariable, myTemporaryValue);
    visitChildren();
    ...
}
// previous value of myVariable is restored
```

The variable will revert to its previous value when the temporary assignment object goes out of scope.  What is a better way to do this?

Comment: That seems optimal to me.  What kind of answer do you anticipate?

Comment: @wallyk, the usage is awkward.  It would be nice to have the template type inferred automatically, and perhaps to write this more like an assignment, but I'm not sure how to pull that off without std::pair.  As for anticipated answers, I half expect someone will point me toward a well-known pattern, or will point out possible pitfalls as Steve Jessop has done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks OK to me except that the destructor can throw, which is bad. `swap` with the original value instead of assigning (edit: this deals with `std::string`, but see the comments for possible problems with classes that are less user-friendly than `string`).

If you back off a little from this part of the code, perhaps you can find a way to not need to set a temporary value at all. Shared mutable state in an object can be bad for the same reason that mutable globals are bad, but to a lesser extent because it only messes up your class instead of messing up your whole program.

For example perhaps you could copy the whole object, set a new value for the variable and visit the copy instead of visiting yourself. Obviously that's not necessarily possible or efficient, you have to look for alternatives on a case by case basis. Maybe the copy can be shallow as far as the children are concerned (i.e. refer to the same child objects), that might be sufficient to make it cheap.

Regarding usage, you could deduce the type like this (untested code):

```
template <typename T, typename ARG>
TemporaryAssignment<T> temp_value(T &var, ARG &&newvalue) {
    return TemporaryAssignment(var, std::forward<ARG>(newValue));
}
```

Usage:

```
auto t = temp_value(myVariable, myTemporaryValue);
```

Then you need a move constructor for TemporaryAssignment:

```
template <typename TYPE> class TemporaryAssignment {
    // change data member
    TYPE *mVariable;
    TYPE mOriginalValue;
public:
    TemporaryAssignment(TYPE &inVariable, TYPE inValue) 
    : mVariable(&inVariable), mOriginalValue(std::move(inVariable)) {
        *mVariable = std::move(inValue);
    }
    TemporaryAssignment(TemporaryAssignment &&rhs) {
        mOriginalValue = std::move(rhs.mOriginalValue);
        mVariable = rhs.mVariable;
        rhs.mVariable = 0;
    }
    ~TypeAssignment() {
        using std::swap;
        if (mVariable) {
            swap(*mVariable, mOriginalValue);
        }
    }
    // can't remember whether this is needed
    TemporaryAssignment(const TemporaryAssignment &) = delete;
    TemporaryAssignment &operator=(const TemporaryAssignment &) = delete;
    TemporaryAssignment &operator=(TemporaryAssignment &&) = delete;
};
```

I thought a bit about specifying `operator=` for `TemporaryAssignment` so as to make the usage look like an assignment, but I didn't come up with anything good.

```
auto t = (temporary(myVariable) = myTemporaryValue);
```

is plausible, but you probably don't want `TemporaryAssignment` to have `operator=` defined because the meaning of:

```
t = otherTemporaryValue;
```

isn't necessarily clear and probably shouldn't be allowed. Maybe with a second class to be returned from `temporary`, and that returns `TemporaryAssignment` from its `operator=`.

Comment: Also, using `swap` or (C++11) `move` for the initial copies would be more efficient in some cases (e.g. `string`).

Comment: why would `swap` not throw?  Doesn't it depend on the assignment and copy constructor?  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/

Comment: @xiaoyi: assignment copies the string, and to do that it (usually) allocates memory, which can fail.

Comment: @japriess: `std::string` has a swap member function which does not throw, and an overload of the free `swap` function that calls it. Other well-written classes will likewise provide a nothrow swap. But you have a point, if this template is supposed to work with badly-written classes for which there is no way to assign the old value back with a guarantee of success, then there's a problem here. Allowing the destructor to throw (and perhaps the program to `terminate`) might be the only way out. Catching and ignoring the failure is wrong, it doesn't restore the variable to the required state.

Comment: @SteveJessop The use of `swqp` is fine for the standard classes (and, we could argue, for any well written class).  You still have the problem with various user defined classes, where there might not be a specialized `swap`, and assignment (or copy) may throw.

Comment: @James: agreed. If you can think of a way out let's have it, but I think that an exception or `terminate` might be as good as it gets for badly written classes. The problem is that the questioner wants a guarantee that the original value is restored on exit from the scope. But if the type of the variable doesn't allow that to be guaranteed then the problem is intractable, hence terminate. In C++11, a constraint on the template parameter that it must be nothrow swappable (or nothrow movable) might be wise.

Comment: @SteveJessop I can't think of a way out, I'm just saying.  I actually use something very similar myself; in practice, I've never actually needed it except for built-in types, so I've lucked out.  The exception issue is generally a problem with RAII.  (On the other hand, not using RAII has even more probems.  We just have to be aware of it.)

Comment: @SteveJessop, very interesting.  I'll admit that move assignments and auto type inference are new to me, and the project I'm working on cannot mandate the use of C++11, but thanks for expanding my horizons.

Answer (score 2):

`swap` is not the best solution, because if `TYPE` has a `std::string` member, the crash problem might happen too.
I think we can use some methods like this:

```
char buffer[sizeof(TYPE)];
memcpy(buffer, &mVariable, sizeof(TYPE));
memcpy(&mVariable, &mOriginalValue, sizeof(TYPE));
memcpy(&mOriginalValue, buffer, sizeof(TYPE));
```

Comment: If this were a generally-valid way to swap two values of any type, then `std::swap` would use it. It isn't, but there are a lot of types that it will work for. Including some of the badly-written types for which `swap` can throw, but not necessarily including all of the well-written types for which `swap` cannot throw.

Comment: `struct Foo { int a; int *ptr_to_a; Foo() : a(0), ptr_to_a(&a) {}; Foo(const Foo &rhs) : a(rhs.a), ptr_to_a(&a) {}; Foo &operator=(const Foo &rhs) { a = rhs.a; }; ~Foo() { assert(&a == ptr_to_a); }`. By copying this type with `memcpy` instead of `operator=`, you violate the class invariant that's asserted in the destructor.

Comment: For a slightly less pointless example, imagine a class that registers itself with some kind of central manager (which perhaps has an index from the value of `a` to a list of all objects currently holding that value, by pointer). It unregisters itself in its destructor, and updates its registration info when assigned, because its value of `a` has changed and so the lists need to be updated. If you copy with `memcpy` then the central register is not updated, and holds incorrect information, so the class won't work properly any more. `memcpy` breaks encapsulation that copy assignment enforces.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the answer from Steve Jessop. From the RIIA (or RAII) point of view, your classes' destructor might end up acquiring resource(memory) where it should only be releasing resources. To avoid this, you could probably think of using a myVar which points to right object at the right time, so new objects could be rightly created only at construction or acquisition time and only delete and pointer re-assignment would happen at the time of release.